# Add an onclick function to existing HTML code with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My task is to inject a custom JS function to an HTML code where we cannot edit buttons and HTML it self, just inject some custom HTML code through GUI. What I have in the code:

```
<input class="ContinueAsAGuest LinkButton" name="submitForm" type="submit" value="Continue as a guest &gt;" />
```

What I need:

```
<input class="ContinueAsAGuest LinkButton" name="submitForm" type="submit" value="Continue as a guest &gt;" onclick = "captureOutcome()" />
```

I wanted to use DOM, but I failed, I stay get the original code. This what I have:

```
var guest = getElementsByClassName("ContinueAsAGuest LinkButton");

guest.onclick = "captureOutcome()";

function captureOutcome(
{'eventName':'event registration','eventAction':'start' }
);
```

I am guessing what I miss is to add the actual `onclick` to the original code.
Am I on the right path?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is a collection....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName` to get the element with that class name and if that is a unique class then use `[0]` to get the reference of that element. By getting the reference you can associate a click function into it.

```js
var guest = document.getElementsByClassName("ContinueAsAGuest LinkButton")[0];

guest.onclick = captureOutcome;

function captureOutcome(){
  alert('clicked!');
};
```

```html
<input class="ContinueAsAGuest LinkButton" name="submitForm" type="submit" value="Continue as a guest &gt;" />
```